# Always Expand groups on export/print of an rdlc report SSRS(even if user has explicitly collapsed the group)

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-grouping

I am facing a problem in creation of an rdlc ssrs report.

Scenario  is as follows:

- The report has Expand all/Collapse all radiobutton option to toggle a group's visibility.
- Report should always be in expanded state if exported to pdf,word etc or printed(even if currently it is collapsed by the user).

This is implemented in rdl report by using a global inbuilt variable “RenderFormat” (below is the condition used over the grouped region which is to be expanded in case of exports/print from the toolbar )

To show expanded data when report is rendered/or printed:

```
=iif(Parameters!ExpandAll.Value = 0,iif(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "WORD" or Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL" or 

Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "PDF" or Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "MHTML" or Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "IMAGE",false,true),False)
```

However the said variable is unavailable to use in local reports.

How can I implement it for RDLC of the same report?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't available in Reporting Services. Unfortunately, the Export feature doesn't fire any sort of event for your code to run. However the report looks when you choose to export it is how it will be rendered in Excel.

One solution would be to include a button to Expand All with instructions to press that before exporting.